# Manipulating VCF files : [E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for 'ABC.vcf.gz' => the file is too big

Tags: python-3.x

how can we deal with too big file ?

The thing is that we have a file of 1.0 GB. The error shows
"[E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for ABC.vcf.gz"

from pysam import VariantFile

vcf = VariantFile('ABC.vcf.gz')

After running codes above, [E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for 'ABC.vcf.gz'.

Thanks in advance